# There seems to be a flock of people whose mission is to close questions

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I understand that we need to keep things clean and not have a bunch of repeat questions but people seem like all they want to do is close a question when there really are good opportunities for discussion.

Here is an example. [image]

I'm the only person actually trying to talk about the question and there are at least 3 other people aside from the OP and me who just want to close out the question.

The question isn't that broad and this sort of behavior where people think they're being constructive by exclusively detracting from the conversation is the type of things that drives people away from the community.

I know I'm not the only person who feels like stack is a little toxic sometimes but what are we doing about this? Can we limit people in how much they remove based on topics they actually participate in? or something! This is one of the few places on the internet where we have such an active community of programmers and thinks actively sharing knowledge and it is a shame to see it stifled by self elected moderators who want to contribute.

Comment: Is "flock" really the right collective noun here? It just doesn't sound right. I'd recommend either "a slam of closers" or perhaps even "an ouroboros of closers".

Comment: With the group, do you mean [SOCVR](https://socvr.org), a large group of people involved with close vote reviewing and maintaining site quality, and working together with the moderators to do so? One simple thing you could do is just visit the [chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and talk about why the question should stay open. They might even reopen it for you.

Comment: Regardless of whether the question should be closed or not: Your answer is definitely not a proper answer. Even when leaving away the unnecessary ascci art, "Yes and no" without any further explanation is neither helpful nor appropriate. I can perfectly see why the comment thinks that you are trolling the op.

Comment: Also, your answer triggered [Smoke Detector](https://charcoal-se.org/#whats-smokey), an important moderation bot. That probably drew a lot of attention to the question

Comment: @Shog9: "*I'd recommend either "a slam of closers" or perhaps even "an ouroboros of closers".*" Actually, I think the group term for crows is most appropriate. "A murder of closers."

Comment: As you have 3K you can cast a re-open vote yourself which puts the question in the re-open queue where also a flock of people is gaming for badges. SOCVR does take reopen-pls requests but it is a tough crowd there so I doubt the example question will get lots of support.

Comment: @Nicol my favorite term for this is the one for pandas.... An embarrassment of pandas. Now it's not appropriate here to use I'd say... But I still think we can find a way to use that somewhere

Comment: Well, since there is also a seethe of users asking bad qestions, I guess it's just as well.

Comment: You said "there really are good opportunities for discussion." while the tour say "It's not a discussion forum." ==> the question should be closed.

Comment: I would have voted to close it as unclear what you're asking. I can't even figure out what the question is.

Answer (score 63):

Yes, there are lots of people who take time out of their day to close inappropriate questions. There's even [an entire review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close) dedicated to it.

And, let's be honest: that isn't a very good question. Maybe it doesn't need to be closed, but if it's going to stay open it needs to be able to attract a really good answer - which given the brevity with which it is written, I doubt will happen.

Also, that brings us to your answer: there's a reason the minimum answer length is 30 characters, and it isn't that we all love ASCII art; you're supposed to **explain *why* "yes" or "no" is the answer to the question**. Even if the asker didn't ask for that explicitly, if they didn't need an explanation they could've just flipped a coin.

Comment: I did explain in the comment, as I started to think about the question I could see it actively getting down votes. I just feel like when I try to write answers I am fighting against the clock or sailing on a sinking ship as questions are constantly closing.

Comment: @kpie Don't be the [fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

Comment: @kpie and comment is not the place for explaining the answer. You could/should have put that explanation in the answer in the first place.

Comment: If you're not into racing, then don't @kpie - seek out questions you can really sink your teeth into. Queue 'em up, let your subconscious work on the problems. Then answer. And always edit the question before you post an answer - that's the preface to your answer, and you want it to be a good one.

Comment: @kpie If you think questions are wrongly closed, make a meta post about it. I don't think so.

Comment: @Shog9 Yes, it isn't a very good question, but -- "but if it's going to stay open it needs to be able to attract a really good answer" -- if it's closed then how can answers be posted?

Comment: @user202729 it cqan be reopened if/when the user provides some context for the 'susbstring', 'subsequence', eg 'one is my actual homework questiion, and one is the title of this code I found on the net [link]. I want you to tell me that the net code answers  the question so I can hand it in'.  I would have close-voted immediate as 'Unclear', with a comment 'Please provide more context', (since OP has >50 rep).

Comment: @Shog9 I'm not racing, it's just that I don't understand the down votes most of the time. Like on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139858/methods-for-determining-temporal-covariance-among-many-time-series/50140756#50140756
Aside from my answer the only attention it's got is down votes, but not even on the question, just on my answer.

Comment: Edit the question, @kpie... I know it seems trivial, but even some paragraph breaks would help.